# Новичок в Git. Необходимо закоммититься в свой проект

Tags: windows, git, github

Форкнул репозиторий с тестовым заданеим по JS, выполнил его, а теперь необходимо закоммититься в свой проект. Как это сделать?
P.S. работаю в Windows

Comment: добавьте в вопрос из какой операционной системы работаете

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/ru/

Comment: скорее всего так в консоли

    git add .
    git commit -m "commit message"
    git push
теперь идете в свой github аккаунт, проверяете, что все запушилось.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Answer (score 3):

Все так, как написал @KoVadim:

---

скорее всего так в консоли:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push
```

теперь идете в свой *github*-аккаунт, проверяете, что все запушилось.

---

От себя хочу порекомендовать [литературу](http://git-scm.com/book/ru) по этой теме и вот такую [хаутушку](http://githowto.com/ru).

Answer (score 2):

`git gui` откроет графический интерфейс. Там в разделе repository->visualize all branch history можешь наглядно убедится, что ты находишься в нужном месте. Кнопки коммита:  stage -> потом commit -> потом  push.
У графического интерфейса есть свои недостатки (например, он не пишет ошибку, если не удался пуш), но для начала, думаю, пойдет.